# Rails: syntax for variables in identifiers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, syntax

Anyone know what the syntax is for using variables in identifiers? i.e.:

```
for a in @issue.articles 
  f.select "article#{a.page}", options_from_collection_for_select(@articles, 'id', 'name', @issue.article2)
end
```

Where the `2` in `@issue.article2` could be an iterator in a `for` loop.

Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean, "variables in objects"? `a2` is an identifier, there's no separation of `a` and `2`. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I meant a variable in an identifier. I'm trying to make each select box dynamically, and I need the identifiers to be named `a1`, `a2`, and `a3`. Does that make sense?

Comment: What identifiers? The fourth param to `o_f_c_f_s` is the selected value, what's @i?

Comment: `@i` is an issue of a magazine, `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` are articles therein. I want the default articles in each issue to be selected by default.

Comment: You need to provide more context. Or just put `@i.a1` etc. into an array and iterate over it; `[@i.a1, @i.a2, ...].each { |a| ... }`. (Although ideally I'd think that a magazine would have a collection of articles, rather than being limited to a hard-coded quantity.)

Comment: Hopefully this provides more context:

Comment: It doesn't. But when it does, it should be in the question, not in comments.

Comment: `for a in @issue.articles`
`f.select "article#{a.page}", options_from_collection_for_select(@articles, 'id', 'name', @issue.articles)`. Does that help? Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: Again, that should go into the question, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean dynamic method names. Here's how:

```
number = 2
@issue.send("article#{number}")
```

See [Variables in ruby method names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300705/variables-in-ruby-method-names).